# In AWS Step Functions, can you format parameter values with static string?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

In AWS Step Functions, we can use parameters from previous steps as inputs using the following syntax.

```
"Parameters": {
        "Details": {
          "weight.$": "$.product.weight",
          "unit": "grams"
        }
      }
```

As an example, say `product.weight.` is `500`. Can I configure a parameter that will receive a value of `500 grams`?

For example, something like this:

```
"Parameters": {
        "Details": {
          "formatted_weight.$": "{$.product.weight} grams",
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `States.Format` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) to interpolate a string:

```json
"Parameters": {
        "Details": {
          "formatted_weight.$": "States.Format('{} grams', $.product.weight)",
        }
      }
```