# Is there a way to use AWS Step Functions Input to assembly command string on System Manager block?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-step-functions, aws-ssm

I am creating a Step Function State machine to everytime an instance starts it copy a file from S3 to an specific folder inside this instance. The origin folder inside S3 bucket has a folder named with this instance ID. The instance ID I am passing as input for the System manager block, but I need to use it to create the command string that will be performed inside the EC2.

For example:

My input is: $.detail.instance-id (lets assume the following ID i-11223344556677889)

The Systems Manager API parameters are:

````
  "CloudWatchOutputConfig": {
    "CloudWatchLogGroupName": "myloggroup",
    "CloudWatchOutputEnabled": true
  },
  "DocumentName": "AWS-RunShellScript",
  "DocumentVersion": "$DEFAULT",
  "InstanceIds.$": "States.Array($)",
  "MaxConcurrency": "50",
  "MaxErrors": "10",
  "Parameters": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "runuser -l ec2-user -c \"aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/**MY_INSTANCEID**/myfile.xyz /home/ec2-user/myfolder/myfile.xyz\""
      }
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 6000
}```
````

Summing up, I want to turn the line with the command replacing the MY_INSTANCEID by my input $.detail.instance-id, and perform the following command:

"runuser -l ec2-user -c "aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/**i-11223344556677889**/myfile.xyz /home/ec2-user/myfolder/myfile.xyz""

Is there a way? I already tried to use the Fn::join withou success.

Thank you in advance,
kind regards,

Winner

Comment: Check out this question. Does States.Format work for your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70766536/in-aws-step-functions-can-you-format-parameter-values-with-static-string.

Comment: why not use ec2 user-data?  That already runs at boot in the context of the instance https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html you can get the ID from the instance metadata service: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html.  I'm not sure why you'd key the object path off instance ID, as you won't know them beforehand.  If you modify some base file for each instance, you may as well pull the template and modify it on the instance

Comment: @RegisterSole, I've tryed this as solution but I got stuck. I don't know if I am having a mistake using all those quotes

`"Parameters": {
    "commands.$": "States.Format('runuser -l ec2-user -c \"aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/{}/myfile.xyz /home/ec2-user/myfolder/myfile.xyz\"', $.detail.instance-id)"
  },`

I getting the following error:
The value for the field 'commands.$' must be a valid JSONPat

Comment: @DanielFarrell, if theres no possibility to do using Step Functions maybe this can be the solution.

Comment: @WinnerMartins Backslash is a special character. See the reserved character section here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html. I'm not sure the correct way though, I think either escape it like instead of `\"`, use `\\"`, or maybe if it doesn’t work remove it altogether `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to use `State.Format` inside the `State.Array` so the it worked, and `State.Format` inside the `State.Array` cannot have quotes:

````
  "CloudWatchOutputConfig": {
    "CloudWatchLogGroupName": "myloggroup",
    "CloudWatchOutputEnabled": true
  },
  "DocumentName": "AWS-RunShellScript",
  "DocumentVersion": "$DEFAULT",
  "InstanceIds.$": "States.Array($)",
  "MaxConcurrency": "50",
  "MaxErrors": "10",
  "Parameters": {
    "commands.$": "States.Array(States.Format('runuser -l ec2-user -c \"aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/**MY_INSTANCEID**/myfile.xyz /home/ec2-user/myfolder/myfile.xyz\"', $))"
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 6000
}```
````

Was also necessary to use `.$` after `command`.